# Missing Parameters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Seller Profile has one seller. I am trying to post the seller profile details and assigning the seller_id to the current_seller. I am however, running into this error. I don't understand why the error says missing parameter because it seems all the needed params have being provided.

Error is get is ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: seller_profiles

```
def create
    @seller_profile = SellerProfile.new(seller_profile_params)
    @seller_profile.seller = current_seller

    respond_to do |format|
      if @seller_profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Seller profile was successfully created.' }
```

```
def seller_profile_params
      params.require(:seller_profile).permit(:first_name, :other_name, :last_name, :email)
    end
```

```
<%= form_tag seller_seller_profiles_path do |form| %>
  <% if seller_profile.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(seller_profile.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this seller_profile from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% seller_profile.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :first_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :other_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :other_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :last_name %>
    <%= text_field_tag :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag :email %>
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
resources :sellers, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index, :destroy] do
    resources :seller_profiles
  end
```

Comment: You should show the log on the server, it will show you the params you are getting. How do you know the params are being provided? you should also show the form that triggers that request. EDIT: also, your error says `seller_profiles` (plural) but your code shows `seller_profile` (singular), are you showing the right error/code?

Comment: Try debug your method `seller_profile_params` and look the value of `params`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `form_for` or the `form_with` helpers instead of `form_tag`. Those helper methods will take care of adding the wrapping `seller_profile` key.

```
<%= form_for seller_profile do |form| %>
  <% if seller_profile.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(seller_profile.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this seller_profile from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% seller_profile.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :first_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :other_name %>
    <%= form.text_field :other_name %>
  </div>

  ... replicate the same change for the rest of the fields ...

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not only that but using `form_for`/`form_with model: seller_profile` will also bind the inputs to the model so that the entire form will not be blanked out on an invalid submission. `form_with` also replaces both `form_for` and `form_tag` with a single call signature.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is `(param is missing or the value is empty: seller_profiles`, it's because you require `:seller_profile`, not `:seller_profiles` in your `params.require`

Comment: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"Osborne", "other_name"=>"Ofosu", "last_name"=>"Saka", "email"=>"osbornebm406@gmail.com", "commit"=>"Save changes", "seller_id"=>"1"}

Comment: Can you add the code for the form to your question?